# Calculate the integral : $\iiint_G xysin(yz)$ While $0\leq x\leq\pi, 0 \leq y \leq 1, 0\leq z \leq \pi/6$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the following integral :

$\iiint_G xy\sin(yz)$

While

$$0\leq x\leq\pi, 0 \leq y \leq 1, 0\leq z \leq \pi/6$$

This what I did (I got the wrong answer).

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_0^\pi xy\sin(yz)dxdzdy=
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_0^\pi x^2y\sin(yz)dxdzdy=$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/6} y\sin(yz)dzdy=
(t=yz,dt=y)=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/6} \sin(t)dtdy$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/6} -cos(t)dtdy=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/6} -\cos(yz)dzdy$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int_0^1 -\cos(\pi/6*y)+1dy=
\frac{\pi^2}{2}\int_0^1 -\sin(\pi/6*y)+ydy$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2} (-\sin(\pi/6*1)+1)=2.4674011$$

I don't understand what's wrong any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your method is correct. Check out the calculations.

Comment: $\sin(\pi/6)=1/2$ - you should be writing your final answers exactly at this stage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is equal to

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi} dx \, x \int_0^1 dy \, y \, \int_0^{\pi/6} dz \, \sin{y z} &= \int_0^{\pi} dx \, x \int_0^1 dy \, \left [ 1-\cos{\left ( \frac{\pi}{6} y \right ) }\right ]\\ &= \frac{\pi^2}{2} \left [1-\frac{6}{\pi}\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}} \right ] \\ &= \frac{\pi^2}{2} - \frac{3 \pi}{2}  \end{align}$$

It appears you forgot the $6/\pi$ factor in front of the sine that results when integrating the cosine.